# Why i cannot remove database?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, root, vesta

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| admin_default      |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| openvpn-admin      |
| performance_schema |
| roundcube          |
+--------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> drop database 'openvpn-admin';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''openvpn-admin'' at line 1
MariaDB [(none)]> drop database openvpn-admin;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-admin' at line 1
MariaDB [(none)]>
```

I'm triggered.
mariadb + vestacp
i cannot delete database WHY?
what's goin on???

Comment: As soon as soon as I saw "I'm triggered", I knew this was going to be a bad post. Remove the lorem ipsum and actually paste the error that you are getting rather than a screenshot.

Comment: I cannot see the text in the image! im using mobile phone. pls post it as a text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's down to your use of "-" in the schema name.

You quote identifiers with backticks ` or double quotes " (if you have ANSI_QUOTES sql_mode enabled) so it will work with

```
drop database `openvpn-admin`;
```

Comment: GOSH tahnk you very much.
setup sql mode directly in command line through SSH.
mysql -u root
--sql-mode ANSI_QUOTES;
or<br/>
SET sql_mode = 'modes';
or
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'modes';
smt like that.

Comment: I'd set it in config so it survives a restart. Have to say I'm not a fan of ANSI_QUOTES they make it much harder to read the code, I only added that to the answer for the sake of completeness.